# rewrite the bash script in an efficient way to run based on server

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script and snippet of a logic is to get the process running on a server, I have a function `stat_check` has some steps to perform.

I am wondering, is there any efficient way of doing this and decreasing number of lines.

Goal - want to pass a unique variable to `stat_check` based on server. I can have list of servers on a separate file and/or in a variable mentioned below as `Servers`.

```
Servers=(flipunix1 flipunix2 flipunix3 flipunix7)
for i in ${Servers[*]}
do
if [ "$SERVER_NAME" == "$i" ];
  then
    stat_check twitter
    stat_check appcreds
    break 2
fi
done

if [ "$SERVER_NAME" == flipunix5 ];
then
stat_check twitter_stats
stat_check relishprogram
fi
```

Comment: I did not, unless I am missing the point, GNU parallel is not the right use case here. isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case statement would be appropriate here:

```sh
case "$SERVER_NAME" in
  flipunix1 | flipunix2 | flipunix3 | flipunix7)
    stat_check twitter
    stat_check appcreds
    ;;
  flipunix5)
    stat_check twitter_stats
    stat_check relishprogram
    ;;
esac
```

Since you're using shell patterns there, you *could* write

```sh
case "$SERVER_NAME" in
  flipunix[1237] ) ...
  flipunix[5]    ) ...
```

Comment: I thought of `case` option , but I have so many servers. As I said this is a snippet.

Also is this right way of representing? 

`case "$SERVER_NAME" in
  flipunix[1237]  | flip[12]) ...
  flipunix[5]    ) ...`

Comment: Yes, the pipes are separators for a list of patterns

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case

Answer (score 0):

An associative array would cut out the loop:

```
declare -A Servers=([flipunix1]="." [flipunix2]="." [flipunix3]="." [flipunix7]=".")

if [ "${Servers[$SERVER_NAME]}" ]
  then
    stat_check twitter
    stat_check appcreds
fi

if [ "$SERVER_NAME" == flipunix5 ]
then
    stat_check twitter_stats
    stat_check relishprogram
fi
```

When I run the above I get:

```
$ SERVER_NAME=fsdfa bash test
$ SERVER_NAME=flipunix1 bash test
test: line 4: stat_check: command not found
test: line 5: stat_check: command not found
$
```

You can also do something clever with the data then too, e.g.:

```
declare -A Servers=([flipunix1]="normal" [flipunix2]="normal" [flipunix3]="normal" [flipunix7]="normal" [flipunix5]="stats")

case "${Servers[$SERVER_NAME]}" in
normal)
    stat_check twitter
    stat_check appcreds
;;
stats)   
    stat_check twitter_stats
    stat_check relishprogram
;;
esac
```

Comment: I did not understand what the script is doing, could you please explain me?

Comment: `Servers` is an associative array - so instead of being accessed by index (1,2,3...) it's accessed by a unique string (in this case, `SERVER_NAME`).  Associative arrays are pretty common in modern programming languages, you can learn about them in general on the internet, or the bash implementation from `man bash` and finding the `Arrays` section.  The case is just a normal case statement, so you lookup the value for `SERVER_NAME` from `Servers`, and depending what it is, take some action.

Comment: If you have lot's of data, you might consider putting it all in a separate file, and sourcing that file in your script(s).